# How to use a constructor in DBFlow

Tags: java, android, orm, dbflow

I am trying to use a constructor in class that extends the BaseModel in DBFlow but i get this in the console.

```
/home/christoandrew/Documents/Trumeter/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/iconasystems/android/trumeter/models/Session_Table.java:144: error: constructor Session in class Session cannot be applied to given types;
return new Session();         ^
  required: String,String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

and this is my Session.java

```
@Table(database = TrumeterDatabase.class)
public class Session extends BaseModel{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    @SerializedName("username")
    String username;
    @Column
    @SerializedName("password")
    String password;

    public Session(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Now when i check the table class generated it has no arguments in the instantiation. I have been checking around and all tutorials don't seem to be having constructors in their classes. Is the mistake mine or thats how its supposed to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You must implement a default constructor for your model classes.

`public Session() {
}`

Because DBflow processor generated code (YourModel_Table) use this default constructor.